# error using unicode on bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a situation where bootstrap is not reading unicode properly while simply html/css is diplaying the unicode as is.

![the above one is error and the below one is the expected outcome][1]

Whats happening? What should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the code in your page head include atleast the following?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>....</title>
</head>
```